# Why is &nbsp; different from " " while comparing

Tags: javascript, regex, whitespace

Can you please explain me why I'm getting `false` while comparing `text === ' '` in this case?

```js
var div = document.getElementById('d');

div.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';

// ' '
var text = div.innerText;

console.log(/\s/.test(' ')); // true
console.log(/\s/.test(text)); // true
console.log(text === ' '); // false
```

```css
#d {
  border: 1px solid;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="d"></div>
```

It seems to be not logic: `\s` is A, `' '` is B, `text` is C.

```
A  = B
A  = C
B != C ???
```

Comment: "*It seems to be not logic: \s is A, ' ' is B, text is C.*" if `A` is `Animal`, `B` is `Dog` and `C` is `Cat`, does the equation still make sense?

Comment: The HTMLEntity `&nbsp;` is not the same as the space character.

Comment: @VLAZ If `Animal` is `Dog`, `Animal` is `Cat` and `Dog` is NOT `Cat`, you're right.

Comment: a `space` is a `\u0020` while &nbsp; is a [`no-break space` which is unicode `\u00A0`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm) which prevent line break, look alike but not the same character

Comment: @Tân precisely. `\s` means *whitespace*, so both the others are a type of whitespace but not the same whitespace character.

Comment: @VLAZ It would be appreciated if you post an answer about *whitespace inheritance*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The space `" "` and the [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) are two different characters. The non-breaking space has a code unit of 160, whereas the space has a code unit of 32.

Going off this observation, the spec uses the following logic when strict equality is used between two non-numeric types:

[**7.2.13 SameValueNonNumeric ( x, y )**](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-samevaluenonnumeric)

> The internal comparison abstract operation SameValueNonNumeric(x, y),
> where neither x nor y are numeric type values, produces true or false.
> Such a comparison is performed as follows:
>
> - Assert: Type(x) is not Number or BigInt. Assert: Type(x) is the same
>   as Type(y).
> - If Type(x) is Undefined, return true. If Type(x) is Null,
>   return true.
> - If Type(x) is String, then
> - If x and y are exactly the
>   same sequence of code units (same length and same code units at
>   corresponding indices), return true; otherwise, return false.
>   ...

The last statement above is not true as both have different code unit values (as seen above), and so, we get `false` when you try and compare the two. This shouldn't be too surprising as we're comparing two different strings (as indicated by their code unit values).

When you use `\s` in a regular expression, however, you're referring to special whitespace characters:

> Matches a single white space character, including space, tab, form feed, line feed, and other Unicode spaces. Equivalent to
>
> ```
> [ \f\n\r\t\v\u00a0\u1680\u2000-\u200a\u2028\u2029\u202f\u205f\u3000\ufeff]
> ```
>
> - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Character_Classes#types)

The character set above includes both the space character (seen at the beginning of the character set) and the non-breaking space (which has a Unicode encoding of `U+00A0`), and so both your tests using regular expressions will return true.

Comment: I haven't thought about checking code point before. Thanks for that.

Comment: @Tân that's alright. The code unit values are often a good thing to look at :)

Answer (score 2):

`&nbsp;` is not the same as a space. This becomes apparent once you learn what these for letters stand for: "non-breaking space". That is, it is (the HTML encoding of) a special space character on which the typesetter is told not to (line)break (among other things).

It simply isn't the same as a (breaking) space, it just visually looks the same. Non-breaking characters can also come in other widths than just that of a single space.

It is, however, considered a whitespace character and this is partially the reason why eg regular expressions have special whitespace character classes (`\s`) and why you should use them (because they are not just a shortcut for "space or tab").

Comment: You would want to add, to make a string equivalent to &nbsp in JS. You can use String.fromCharCode(160) since character code of &nbsp is 160.

Comment: Really helpful.Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In cases like these where you have two visually similar characters, the easiest way examine *why* they are considered unequal is to examine *what* the characters are:

```js
var divB = document.getElementById('b');
var divC = document.getElementById('c');

var textB = divB.textContent;
var textC = divC.textContent;

var charB = textB.charCodeAt(0);
var charC = textC.charCodeAt(0);

console.log(charB);
console.log(charC);
```

```html
<div id="b">&nbsp;</div> <!-- nbsp entity -->
<div id="c"> </div> <!-- a single space -->
```

So, they have two *different* character codes, which means they are different characters. Thus `B != C` makes sense - they aren't the same.

A space is a type of whitespace character, while the `nbsp;` entity represents a **n**on-**b**reaking **sp**ace - essentially an atomic whitespace that will not be broken up. Here is an example:

```css
.example {
  width: 2em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<h3>Space</h3>
<div class="example">hello world</div>

<h3>Non-breakable space</h3>
<div class="example">hello&nbsp;world</div>
```

The regex symbol `\s` matches *any* whitespace

```js
var newLine = '\n';
var lineFeed = '\r';
var tabCharacter = '\t';
var space = ' ';
var nonBreakableSpace = String.fromCharCode(160);

var whitespaceRegex = /\s/;

console.log(whitespaceRegex.test(newLine));
console.log(whitespaceRegex.test(lineFeed));
console.log(whitespaceRegex.test(tabCharacter));
console.log(whitespaceRegex.test(space));
console.log(whitespaceRegex.test(nonBreakableSpace));
```

So, if the regex matches two things they are not guaranteed to be equivalent - after all a new line is also not the same as a space, nor a tab.

In effect, you can think of `\s` as a *category* of things, thus

```
A  = B
A  = C
B != C
```

makes perfect sense. Let's just replace `A` with `Animal`, `B` with `Dog` and `C` with `Cat` and if we follow the above relations:

1. A dog is an animal
2. A cat is an animal
3. A cat is not a dog

We can't *garantee* 3. but we can definitely say that drawing the conclusion `B = C` is not necessarily correct.

Comment: Wow. I'm wrong while doing math: A = B = C. Now I can think about: Both B and C *inherit* from A but they are not equal. Many thanks!

Answer (score -1):

My Friend ("") shows us Statements no follow as HTML (Tag and Element).
&nbsp Supports in HTML (tags and Element).

" " the gap is fixed in.
nbsp gap is not fixed.

Answer (score -1):

`&nbsp;` is  a whitespace.

' ' is a non interesting whitespace.

The elements containing only a " " may not work, where `&nbsp;` will work. 
If we are rendering any table with empty data it will not apply any styles or the border etc.- when there is no content or white space.
If we are adding `&nbsp;` everything will be shown up!